# Cognos 10 - How to remove 'Deselect' at the bottom of the Radio Button Prompt in Report Studio

Tags: javascript, radio-button, prompt, cognos

I have a Radio Button prompt. It is an optional prompt, therefore "Deselect" appears at the bottom of the prompt. But I would like to remove or hide "Deselect" from this radio button prompt.

Please let me know the Javascript which I can use in an HTML item for this prompt.

I am using Cognos 10.

[image: Radio Button Prompt - Remove Deselect]

Answer (score 3):

This is native functionality in `10.1.1`

Select your value prompt, then find the property `Results Select All Text`. Click the `ellipsis`, click `Specified text`, then `OK`.

Repeat for the `Results Deselect All Text` property.

Answer (score 1):

I really love using jQuery with Cognos. It makes life much more easier to find and manipulate HTML items.
So, after said that, let's dive to solution, which was tested on Cognos 10. I am not sure it will work on Cognos 8.X reports.

Add 2 HTML item to the bottom of the prompt page. Only to the bottom of page, otherwise you'll get script errors.
On first HTML item reference to the jQuery library:

```
 <script language="javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">/**/</script>
```

On this example, I have referenced Google URL, but you can easily download the jQuery library and use it locally on your Cognos web server.
The second HTML is where the actual hiding is done:

```
<script language="javascript">$('a[id*=PRMT_SV_LINK_DESELECT]').hide();</script>
```

This tells jquery ($) to select all the HTML link objects (a) that their id attribute contains PRMT_SV_LINK_DESELECT.
Afterwards it activate the hide function to hide the link.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of JavaScript u can go to "Classes" from "Page explorer" bar and select "Prompt control Hyperlink" class object from "Global Class Extensions" and select class property "Box Type" "None". Then you can disable "select all and deselect all" options to any prompt in cognos.